How to set a autoincrement value in a ELSE condition of CASE expression SQL query
I am trying to select from a table and insert into another table in Microsoft SQL Server where I need to check for a numeric value exist. If it is numeric then insert the actual value else insert an incremental integer value.
Here is a sample query just for the sake of understanding. I am having a similar issue in my project and need to implement this auto-increment of values in the temp table. Or can this numeric check be implemented in a different way?
I tried below query but not sure how to make it auto-incrementing:
SELECT
    custname,
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(custid) = 1 
            THEN custid 
            ELSE 0000 
    END AS [CustomerId] 
FROM
    customerTable

INSERT INTO tempTable name, id

Example
if the customer table has this data:



CustName
CustID




John
340


Jacob
xxx


Jim
342


Tom
yyy


Bill
zzz



I need the temp table to be generated as below:



CustName
CustID




John
340


Jacob
100


Jim
342


Tom
101


Bill
102



I need to ensure the non numeric values are auto incremented from 100.
How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Don't do it like this. Make the CustomerId an IDENTITY column or use a sequence to auto-increment the value. Let's users choosing their own IDs will cause collisions sooner or later.

@CodeDifferent Thanks for the reply. But I just shared it for the sake of understanding. I am having a similar issue in my project where i need to make the temp table column value to some default integers if the actual table value is not numeric.
Need to make it unique in the temp table for the transaction.

MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Please don't use images, use table markdown.

You can use row_number() function  when building your temp table:
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(custid) = 1
    THEN custid
    ELSE 100
        + ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (PARTITION BY ISNUMERIC(custid) ORDER BY custid)
END AS ...

